# Ajax displays div dialog in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Pretty new to ajax.

So I have this div:

```
   <div id="authentication" title="Authentication" >
    <b>Please Generate a new token to continue!</b>
    <br /><br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Token:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtToken"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><label id="lblError"></label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

which is not being displayed on my mvc view because it is a being used as a dialogue box by Ajax code below:

```
$('#authentication').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    width:500,
    resizable: false,
    beforeclose : function() { return false; },
    title: 'Authentication',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function () {
            window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Index", "Home")");
        },
        "Submit": function () {
            var token=$('#txtToken').val();
            var dlg = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'token': token},
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("CheckNewToken", "Account")',
                success: function (result) {
                    if(result==true)
                    {
                        window.parent.jQuery('#authentication').dialog('destroy');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#lblError').html("Incorrect credentials. Please try again");
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
        }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

However when the codes goes to success and result == result, the dialog box is destroyed but the div (dialog box) is then being displayed on my view which I don't want. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the dialog and then destroy. This will hide the dialog completely and then destroy its dialog features. if you just do `.dialog('destroy')` it will just *remove the dialog functionality completely* and display the element as is on the page but it wont hide.

```
success: function (result) {
                    if(result==true)
                    {
                        $('#authentication').dialog('close').dialog('destroy');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#lblError').html("Incorrect credentials. Please try again");
                    }
                },
```

Another thing is `beforeclose : function() { return false; },` you are returning false which will prevent the close event from happening. it should be `beforeClose` though you can remove it safely.

if the above doesnt work another option to remove the div is by subscribing to `close` event:-

```
   $('#authentication').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    width:500,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Authentication',
    modal: true,
    close:function(){

        $(this).dialog('destroy').hide();
     },
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function () {

        },
        "Submit": function () {
            var token=$('#txtToken').val();
            var dlg = $(this);
           $('#authentication').dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you can replicate this is a Fiddle that would help getting in to the issue if not resolved by above solutions.

Comment: Do you have any idea if is possible to send data from dialog box to view but keep it hidden from user (for example to a hidden label/textbox)?

Comment: you want to send it to view or to a control in the same page?

Comment: view so I can send it to the controller

Comment: You could do an ajax call on `close` event and passing the Json POST data or Get  fetching it from the dialog, get the partial view back and update your page. access the value like this `$(this).find('#txtToken')val()` inside the `close` call back function.